# Ruby two comparisons in unless

Tags: ruby

Im ruby beginner and very frustrated with this code:

```
unless ((f[-4..-5] == '.png') || (f[-4..-5] == '.jpg'))
```

Somehow the second comparison is not recognized by ruby! Whats wrong?

Comment: what do you mean by "not recognized"? and what do you expect the code to do?

Comment: What are you trying to do ? f[-4..-5] will always be an empty string/array (depending on what f was to begin with)

Comment: @EmSta That is still not descriptive.  The best way we can help, is if you tell us what you think may be going wrong to the best of your ability.

Comment: What is the value of f ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you should use `f[-4..-1]` instead of `f[-4..-5]`.

Or you can use regular expression:

```
unless f =~ /\.(png|jpg)$/
```

or use [String#end_with?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-end_with-3F):

```
unless f.end_with?('.png', '.jpg')
```

Comment: `unless f[/\.(?:jpe?|pn)g$/]`. Some apps create `jpeg` files and lots of those exist in the wild. `jpg` is the extension I see with "modern" apps though.

Answer (score 4):

`f[-4..-5]` would be an empty string, which will never match `'.png'`. So the second term of your disjunction will never be evaluated.

If you are conditioning by the file extension, then you may do this:

```
case File.extname(f)
when ".png", ".jpg"
else
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

How is below :

```
ext_nm = File.extname(f)
unless [".png", ".jpg"].include? ext_nm
```

Comment: You should assign `File.extname(f)` to a variable otherwise each iteration over the array will force recomputing the extension. That's a waste of CPU time.

Comment: @theTinMan your feed back is always welcome to me...as I am here to learn..so i updated the code... :D